# Can not get series data in Highcharts, Highstock

Tags: highcharts

I want to get all series data in highstock callback function. Please see this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dodoflying/dKDK8/), `serie.data` are all empty array.

The very strange thing is it related to `rangeSelector`. If I set to this way

```
rangeSelector: {
                selected: 4
            },
```

It will return data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following is what the [`series.data`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series%3a%3adata) documentation says

> **data**
>
> Read only. An array with the series' data point objects. In case the
>   series data length exceeds the cropThreshold, or if the data is
>   grouped, series.data doesn't contain all the points. It only contains
>   the points that have been created on demand. In these cases, all
>   original X and Y values can be read from series.xData and
>   series.yData. Additionally, series.options.data contains all
>   configuration objects for the points, whether they be numbers, arrays
>   or objects. Returns
>
> ```
> Array
> ```

`series.data` only contains certain data and not all the points and looking at the source code it seems `series.data` is populated when the series is cropped or translated, hence setting `rangeSelector.selected=4` results in cropping and hence data array is populated. For some reason it appears `series.data` is left empty if all the data is shown, this happens when `rangeSelector.select=5`. I would advice against using `series.data` for this unpredictable behavior

Use `series.points` if you want the points that are currently visible, or use `series.options.data` (or `series.options.xData` or
 `series.options.yData`) to get all data (or xData array or yData array)

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you help to see another question related to Highcharts at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491651/get-wrong-point-ploty-position-in-highcharts-highstock

Comment: Awesim!! I wonder, why series.points is not documented? Still actual btw.