# Get wrong point.plotY position in Highcharts / Highstock

Tags: highcharts

I always get wrong `point.plotY` position when I click `RangeSelector` in Highstock.

Please see this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dodoflying/GLFMY/9/).

I try to catch range change event in `setExtremes: function (e)`. When I click `6m` in rangeselector, in firebug console I print both last point object and point.plotY

You can see that the value of PlotY in the point object and the plotY is different. I also draw 
a path start from  `[chart.plotLeft + chart.plotWidth, chart.plotTop + point.plotY]`, it seems it does not match the last point of the series.

```
xAxis: {
                events: {

                    setExtremes: function (e) {
                        console.log('change');
                        $("#test").remove();

                        $(chart.series).each(function (i, serie) {
                            point = serie.data[serie.data.length - 1];
                            if (point) {
                                console.log(point);
                                console.log(point.plotY);
                                chart.renderer.path(['M', chart.plotLeft + chart.plotWidth, chart.plotTop + point.plotY, 'l', 1, 1])
                                    .attr({
                                    'stroke-width': 10,
                                    stroke: 'red',
                                    id: 'test'
                                })
                                    .add();
                            }

                        });
                    }

                }
            },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code to use [`xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes) instead of [`xAxis.events.setExtremes`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.setExtremes) Also since you probably are referring to the last point in the view port, changed `serie.data` to `serie.points`

```
$(chart.series).each(function (i, serie) {
    point = serie.points[serie.points.length - 1];
    if (point) {
        console.log(point);
        console.log(point.plotY);
        chart.renderer.circle(chart.plotLeft + chart.plotWidth, chart.plotTop + point.plotY, 5)
            .attr({
            'stroke-width': 5,
            stroke: 'red',
            id: 'test'
        }).add();
    }
});
```

[**@jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GLFMY/10/)

Comment: Thank you very much Jugal. If you have time, please help to take a look another highcharts exporting problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508849/can-not-exporting-renderer-shapes-added-in-callback-function-in-highcharts-hig